# Is it possible to add a Canvas App to a Facebook (Place) Location?

Tags: facebook, facebook-canvas

Is it possible to add a Canvas App to a Facebook (Place) Location?

It's easy enough to add them to standard pages, with the following:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=ID_OF_APP&display=popup&next=APP_URL
```

But is it possible to add canvas apps to Locations?  There are "holes" to put them in, but they don't appear in the `add-an-app` dialog that the link above triggers.

Locations to be clear, is what you see from a page's admin menu under "Locations" in the left-hand side.  Each location has its own page like `count`, and `Timeline`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, what a pain.  Listed the solution here:
http://circlical.com/blog/2013/4/15/adding-facebook-applications-canvas-to-location-pages